# Java library for Windows VHD API

Tags: java, windows, jna, vhd

I need to mount and navigate a Windows VHD from Java. Anyone know of a Java library that wraps the [Windows Virtual Hard Drive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323700%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or is there perhaps source code that uses [JNA](http://jna.java.net) that I can look at. My google searches did not give me much.

Even some sample code on how to convert the [OpenVirtualDisk function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323680%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to JNA structures would give me enough to do the rest I believe.

Comment: did you find anything on this.. yet..??

Comment: possible duplicate of [VHD Java library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354335/vhd-java-library)

Comment: @dhroove I've written my own java classes to read VHD files in the end. If there is demand for it then I can make the effort to put it on github as a project perhaps.

Comment: @hannes yes it would be very helpfull

Comment: @HannesdeJager Why not answering your own question with a link to the github project with your classes?

Comment: Yes if I can just find the time to extract those classes and put it in Github. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VHD APIs are on MSDN.  Here is a link to one of the APIs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323692(v=vs.85).aspx

Here is a JNA usage example to load the VHD library with JNA (adjust/define types as necessary):

```
public interface VHDLibrary extends Library {
    VHDLibrary INSTANCE = (VHDLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("VirtDisk", VHDLibrary.class);
    DWORD AttachVirtualDisk(HANDLE p1, Pointer p2, int p3, long p4, Pointer p5, Pointer p6);
}
```

And to invoke the function via JNA (adjust/define params as necessary):

```
VHDLibrary.INSTANCE.AttachVirtualDisk(null, null, 0, 0, null, null);
```