# VHD Java library

Tags: java, virtualization, disk, vhd, diskimage

I'm looking for a Java library that can open .vhd files. I wants to create a program that can navigate inside it. I also want it to be 
cross-platform. I have googled for an library a while now but found nothing. I did only find an **old** unanswerd question [here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245167/java-library-for-windows-vhd-api).
Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java library for Windows VHD API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245167/java-library-for-windows-vhd-api)

Comment: Yes but noone have answered on that question and it is a long time ago when that question was asked, so it is almost forgotten. So I asked it again. Is that impermissible then vote to delete this post.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I'd say the other is a duplicate of this, since this one's slightly more general (not Windows-specific).

Answer (score 1):

Consider [`libguestfs`](http://libguestfs.org/). `libguestfs` is a C library, but it [has a Java binding](http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-java.3.html).

It [claims to be cross-platform](http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-faq.1.html#does_libguestfs_need___libvirt___kvm___red_hat___fedora__), working on Linux and Mac OS X, and "[s]ome virt tools have been ported to Windows". Check to see whether the features you need work on Windows.

`libguestfs` does support VHD images (**under the format name `vpc`**).

#### Obtaining libguestfs

The Java bindings, which contain the `com.redhat.et.libguestfs` package, are available as part of the source distribution tarball. This can be obtained from the [`libguestfs` download page](http://libguestfs.org/download/); select the latest version, currently [1.18.8](http://libguestfs.org/download/1.18-stable/libguestfs-1.18.8.tar.gz).

Alternatively, a pre-compiled JAR might be available from the Maven repository.

Either way, on Windows you likely have to compile the native `libguestfs` library yourself.

Comment: It looks good. But I want my program to run on cross-platform. At least Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.

Comment: @AHugoH: Actually I was mistaken about it being Linux-only. Edited.