# How to Create, mount , unmount VHD's through java program on windows server 2008?

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface, vhd

With reference to [VHD Java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354335/vhd-java-library) , I tried to use `libguestfs`.. but I am unable to get it work. At the first glance it seems that it is not working on the windows environment.

But for the try I am stuck at first point only, how to get jar file for `com.redhat.et.libguestfs.*` classes. I might be wrong in my execution plan.. kindly help.

Is there any better way to achieve my goal of creating , mounting , unmounting VHD's through java program.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Looking at the SO answer you referring to it reads as if libguestfs doesn't really support windows, just Linux and OSX...

Answer (score 0):

The Java bindings, which contain the `com.redhat.et.libguestfs` package, are available as part of the source distribution tarball. This can be obtained from the [`libguestfs` download page](http://libguestfs.org/download/); select the latest version, currently [1.18.8](http://libguestfs.org/download/1.18-stable/libguestfs-1.18.8.tar.gz).

Alternatively, a pre-compiled JAR might be available from the Maven repository.

Either way, on Windows you likely have to compile the native `libguestfs` library yourself.